# Selenium Error HELP C# !: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException :

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

Can anybody help with this Selenium error?

I have one C# solution, with only one Specflow feature with one single tests to navigate to an Url using Chrome driver.

When I run the only test it opens Chrome but does not go to the URL, it throws that error :(

Code snippet

```
namespace MotorClaims.AcceptanceTests.Steps
{
[Binding]
public class Steps
{
    public IWebDriver webDriver;
    public Steps()
    {
           webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    [Given(@"I am at the motor claim homepage")]
    public void GivenIAmAtTheMotorClaimHomepage()
    {
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://XXXXXXX");
    }
```

Comment: _TargetInvocationException_ does not provide optimum information. Try to see _Inner Exception_ to get the root cause which will help us analyzing your issue. Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: Kindly paste error stack trace

Comment: Thanks guys, i found the solution for the issue. It was the version of my Chrome driver. i had to downgrade to 2.37 from 2.40. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found the solution for the issue. It was the version of my Chrome driver. I had to downgrade to 2.37 from 2.40. :) .

it seems like the latest version of Chrome driver is problematic with Chrome browser 64.0.3